# Python cleaning dates for conversion to year only in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a large data set which some users put in data on an csv. I converted the CSV into a dataframe with `panda`. The column is over 1000 entries here is a sample

```
datestart
5/5/2013
6/12/2013
11/9/2011
4/11/2013
10/16/2011
6/15/2013
6/19/2013
6/16/2013
10/1/2011
1/8/2013
7/15/2013
7/22/2013
7/22/2013
5/5/2013
7/12/2013
7/29/2013
8/1/2013
7/22/2013
3/15/2013
6/17/2013
7/9/2013
3/5/2013
5/10/2013
5/15/2013
6/30/2013
6/30/2013
1/1/2006
00/00/0000
7/1/2013
12/21/2009
8/14/2013
Feb 1 2013
```

Then I tried converting the dates into years  using

```
df['year']=df['datestart'].astype('timedelta64[Y]')
```

But it gave me an error:

```
ValueError: Value cannot be converted into object Numpy Time delta
```

Using Datetime64

```
df['year']=pd.to_datetime(df['datestart']).astype('datetime64[Y]')
```

it gave:

```
"ValueError: Error parsing datetime string ""03/13/2014"" at position 2"
```

Since that column was filled in by users, the majority was in this format MM/DD/YYYY but some data was put in like this: Feb 10 2013 and there was one entry like this 00/00/0000. I am guessing the different formats screwed up the processing.

Is there a `try loop`, `if statement`, or something that I can skip over problems like these?

If date time fails I will be force to use a `str.extract` script which also works:

```
year=df['datestart'].str.extract("(?P<month>[0-9]+)(-|\/)(?P<day>[0-9]+)(-|\/)(?P<year>[0-9]+)")


del df['month'], df['day']
```

and use `concat` to take the year out.

With `df['year']=pd.to_datetime(df['datestart'],coerce=True, errors ='ignore').astype('datetime64[Y]')` The error message is:

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    C:\Users\0\Desktop\python\Example.py    23      
    astype  C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py    2062        
    astype  C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py  2491        
    apply   C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py  3728        
    astype  C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py  1746        
    _astype C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py  470     
    _astype_nansafe C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py 2222        
TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [datetime64[Y]]
```

Comment: You should be using `datetime64`, not `timedelta64`.

Comment: @U2EF1 I tried that and it gave a value error see above. Also tried to coerce the format to datetime using `pd.to_date` before trying.

Comment: Show some example data and full error tracebacks

Comment: @joris Done! the traceback is above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first have to convert the column with the date values to datetime's with `to_datetime()`:

```
df['datestart'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datestart'], coerce=True)
```

This should normally parse the different formats flexibly (the `coerce=True` is important here to convert invalid dates to `NaT`).

If you then want the year part of the dates, you can do the following (seems doing astype directly on the pandas column gives an error, but with `values` you can get the underlying numpy array):

```
df['datestart'].values.astype('datetime64[Y]')
```

The problem with this is that it gives again an error when assigning this to a column due to the `NaT` value (this seems a bug, you can solve this by doing `df = df.dropna()`). But also, when you assign this to a column, it get converted back to a `datetime64[ns]` as this is the way pandas stores datetimes. So I personally think if you want a column with the years, you can better do the following:

```
df['year'] =  pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datestart']).year
```

This last one will return the year as an integer.

Comment: I tried  `pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datestart']).year` and it gave an error ValueError unable to convert then it list the columns. I tried `df['datestart'].astype('datetime64[Y]')` and it gave a different ValueError: parsing Datetime string "some date" at position 2

Comment: the conversion had no errors not sure if it did convert all correctly since I have stuff like 00/00/0000.

Comment: You probably have to add `coerce=True` in `to_datetime`, otherwise the values are left untouched if they cannot be parsed. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: and for example: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#invalid-data

Comment: Just tried that also tried `error='ignore'` . So I did this`df['year']=pd.to_datetime(df['datestart'],coerce=True, errors ='ignore').astype('datetime64[Y]')` and got an error `TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [datetime64[Y]]` I think the point full of zeros(00/00/0000) is being misinterpreted as Nanoseconds and the Ignore did not catch it.

Comment: Can you show some example data: a small example array with the initial values, and what you get with the different steps? Also look first at the result of `to_datetime` if this looks OK, and only then try the astype.